# How to enter the GPA of a degree program on a job application?

Tags: applications, work-experience

Some workplace applications ask for the GPA of the degree that a person holds. How should that be entered in a case where half of the degree credits were earned in another institution?

For example: A person does two years' worth of academic course work were completed at institution A, with a GPA 3.5, without graduating from institution A. This person transfers to institution B and all the coursework is transferred as earned credit, but without the GPA score. Upon graduation from institution B, the GPA is 2.5. Should the person enter 2.5 as the GPA for that degree, or 3.0 as the average of the two, assuming the course load was equal in credit/grade ratio?

Comment: You should write whatever you can reasonably prove with academic transcripts. If you have transcripts from both institutions, I would go with the most flattering maths that is not dishonest.

Comment: Once you get your first job, nobody cares at all.

Comment: @Nelson I would tend to agree, but I am seeing this field in an application for a mid-level position, which throws me off.

Comment: FWIW, I asked a [question on meta](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7006/clarification-on-academic-and-academia-tags) regarding the academic tag so you might see another edit on this later.

Comment: @KingsInnerSoul It might be companies trying to collect more data to pump into Machine Learning systems. You can ask them straight up what they plan to do with the information collected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You enter the truthiest value.  When you graduated and got your diploma, from institution B, your GPA was 2.5.  So that's the number you put.  Then you don't have to go back and double-check yourself when you get the job offer and they do a background check on you.  There are at least 2-3 questions per week on this site of the form "I lied on my resume and now they're background checking me and I'm afraid I'll lose the job, what should I do?"; don't be one of those people.

That said, you noted in the comments that this is for a mid-level position.  I would have serious questions for a company that would take your GPA seriously for a mid-level position; for an intro-level or junior-level position sure, but for mid-level nobody cares (usually), and it's somewhat offputting that this company does care.  You may want to ask about that.  A 2.5 GPA is not flattering so you may want to know if this company is even worth applying to at all if your GPA is low.

Comment: I have honestly **never** been asked for my GPA on any job application.  (Although in my case I would be *very* happy to provide it!)

Comment: It is a Tier-1 tech company. I would suspect that it is a default form for all applicants. My desire here to (re)compute the GPA is the possibility that they have an automated screen for candidates with low(er) GPA.

Answer (score 4):

Input what is shown on your transcript.

Most transcripts should show this, regardless of how the credit is split or whatever. It makes it MUCH simpler to verify without doing a bunch of math.

If you are able to calculate a higher GPA using extra credits, you have the option of putting that as additional information, but I wouldn't spend too much time doing this or make it look too cluttered.